# Run init script on datasource devservice in quarkus?

Tags: postgresql, initialization, quarkus, testcontainers

I have a Quarkus project that uses a postgresql datasource. In production, we create the necessary schemas on the db manually before.

When I run quarkusDev mode and use the devservices, I therefor would like to run an init script on the testcontainer to create the schemas before liquibase does its migrations, which otherwise will fail.

I tried this without success

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:13:///quarkus?TC_INITSCRIPT=testcontainer/schema-init.sql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
```

Nothing got picked up by the postgres testcontainer.

How can I run a init script on a datasource testcontainer with quarkus?

Comment: Is the database script you specify on the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here: https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services#database-vendor-specific-configuration

> specific properties supported by the Testcontainers JDBC driver such as TC_INITSCRIPT, TC_INITFUNCTION, TC_DAEMON, TC_TMPFS are not supported.

So this simply does not work